# Adding multiple filter conditions in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have query where I am getting some tickets data.

I need remove the tickets where it contains

```
caseNo='ABC' and InputMethod='Robot' and summary ='MAC'
```

So in my where condition I did like this which is wrong.

```
Left(caseNo,3)='ABC' and InputMethod = 'Robot' and left(summary,5) = 'MAC'
```

Could anybody suggest how to do.

[image]

Comment: What issue are you facing when you try to execute the query with the mentioned where clause. Share the query you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems what you need is:

```sql
WHERE NOT(CaseNo LIKE 'abc%'
      AND InputMethod = 'Robot'
      AND Summary LIKE 'MAC%')
```

Your clause `left(summary,5) = 'MAC'` doesn't make sense, as you take the 5 left most characters, and then pass a `varchar(3)`. That clause is never going to be true unless `summary` has the value `'MAC'`.